# View content inside linux virtual machine without root password

Tags: linux, opensuse

I have a virtual machine, which run opensuse OS, but I forgot root's password, so I cannot login. But I want to view some files inside it. Is there anyway to do it, for example, view the vmdk by another virtual machine, can I do that?

Comment: I would recommend you simply follow the manual  and [recover that lost root password](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Recover_root_password)

Answer (score 0):

How about [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) and especially its `guestfish` interactive console or `guestmount` mount tool?